# openLDAP modify error 80 configuring TLS

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

when I try to modify LDAP with the following code:

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/cacert.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ldap01_slapd_cert.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
```

I get the following error.

```
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Show us what you try exactly.

Comment: Look at slapd logs, with -d -1 to get all info if nothing shown otherwise